# Xpath query with multiple OR not working for windows events

Tags: c++, windows, xpath

I'm using c++ to query event log like in example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/querying-for-events

my query goes like this:

```
*[System[EventID=1102 or EventID=4656 or EventID=4690]]
```

and this part works just fine. The problem occurres when I try to grab more event id's. Above 4 stop working.
Not working example:

```
*[System[EventID=1102 or EventID=4656 or EventID=4690 or EventID=4658 or EventID=4663]]
```

So how can I query multiple event id's?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use structured XML query

```
#define QUERY \
    L"<QueryList>" \
    L"  <Query Path='Security'>" \
    L"     <Select>Event/System[EventID=1102 or EventID=4656 or EventID=4663 or EventID=4656 or EventID=4690]</Select>" \
    L"  </Query>" \
    L"</QueryList>"
```